# Parse deploy is not updating code in my public folder. Is there a setting for caching?

Tags: parse-platform

I am making changes and added new files to the public/ directory inside my Node.js app hosted with Parse Cloud Code.  However, Parse doesn't seem to be tracking these changes when I do a 'parse deploy'.  If I make changes to the main Node.js app, Parse tracks those changes..

Unfortunately, the public/ files are not listed inside the "Files" tab of the "Cloud Code" tab inside my dashboard, so I can't see whether they're being updated.

But if I try something like `curl http://my-app.parseapp.com/js/file.js` I see the older version.  And if I do `curl http://my-app.parseapp.com/js/newFile.js` I don't see the new file I added.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I see it, too.

Comment: It was an error with Parse.  They admitted to it on their support forums.  You may have to ping them there: http://www.parse.com/help

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when building my express app and hosting it on Parse.com. My solve although it was quite annoying was to temporarily move the public folder out of the repo, run `parse deploy` then add the public folder back in and run `parse deploy` once more.

Comment: I had the same issue. I posted a bug report on the parse team. I will keep you posted when they will reply me.

Answer (score 0):

Removing / renaming folders didn't work for me, nor did either `parse deploy` or `parse develop`.

My issue only appeared after creating a function or job with a `-` in the name, for example `schedule-notification`. After removing the hyphens and trying again things seemed to start working.